# Is there a (free) alternative to WinEdt that handles projects in a similar way?

Tags: editors

The title pretty much says it all-- I'm trying to get myself onto open source, or at least freely available, software. I've been using WinEdt forever, and despite its faults, it has one killer feature that I can't seem to go without: the way it handles projects.

I'm sure I am not using it exactly as it was intended: I teach several classes, and I like to save all of the quizzes/exams/syllabi/etc. for each class in its own project file. That way, when I switch from thinking about class A to thinking about class B, I can switch projects and have all of my tex files from class B open up at the same time. WinEdt handles this perfectly by saving all the open files as a project and storing recently used projects in a drop-down menu.

Are there any other LaTeX editors that save projects similarly?

Comment: Both TexnicCentre and Kile have some form of project handling. I haven't used either much though, so I can't say how they compare to WinEdt.

Comment: Also, looking at  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides, WinShell has some project support.

Comment: I migrated both myself and my students to Texmaker.  It has project support.  And it allows you to have more than one main file in the same folder.  So when I create the syllabi for each semester, I have all the boiler plate in separate files with a different main for each course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Kile. It handles projects, the shortcuts are easy to define, and it is free.